# No setting on sub-sites to inherit master page from parent of the site

Tags: master-page, site-settings, inheritance

I am using SharePoint 2010...........

When I create a sub-site and I go to "Site Settings" there is no option that will allow me to inherit site master page from parent of the site.

I have to manually go and type this URL in:

> http://SiteName/SubsiteName/_layouts/ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx

This then will take me to a page where I can set this setting.

**Questions**

1. Why cant I get to this from the Site Settings?
2. Is it possible to change a setting somewhere so that when ever I do create sub-sites to **ALWAYS** inherit the parent **master page** and parent **theme**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In order for this link to show up I think you need to have the Publishing Site and Web features activated.
2. If my memory serves me I think activating the Publishing Web feature inherit at least the master page. Perhaps the Theme as well.

Comment: Number 1 worked for me thanks, but number 2 is still not answered, as I want this feature to ALWAYS be activated. I don't want to go back every time and activate this when I create a new sub-site.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure that the "SharePoint Server Publishing" Feature is always activated somehere maybe in Central Administration?

Answer (score 1):

As Neil mentions, 1 is due to the publishing features - you need them to see that page.

Regarding 2, there is no way out of the box to do this.

If your [branding is applied by a feature](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/30/feature-receiver-to-apply-master-pages/), you could [use feature stapling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861862%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to automatically turn on that branding when a new site is provisioned. This is the normal way of achieving that.

If not, well, you might want to create a feature so that you can do this!

Finally, you really don't want to **always** apply the *same* master page to child sites - certain sites, [like meeting workspaces](http://www.novolocus.com/2008/10/22/setting-a-site-master-on-a-publishing-site-breaks-meeting-workspaces/), use a different master page to 'normal' sites, and changing their master page to a typical 'team site' type one will break their functionality.